# DateTime textbox monthyear only

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert the TEXT in my textbox, format = "MMyyyy" and compare to datetime now = "MMyyyy" the format must be MMyyyy, but my problem is how to convert it back to date to compare them who is higher or lower

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(txtperiodcovered.Text) < DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    MessageBox.Show(@"period cover must be higher than year and month now");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtperiodcovered.Text` exactly?

Comment: Convert it back, from what to what? Your question is confusing.

Comment: Declare a variable that will hold the original value.

Comment: txtperiodcovered.Text = "201010"; and convert it to datetime

Comment: take the YYYY  and MM  of the values from textbox and datetime.now.date and concatenate to YYYYMM and compare

Comment: in datetime i am trying to get the format yyyyMM as string and bring it back to DATETIME

Comment: you cannot convert to date as it does not have day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't feel I understand your problem completely but I think you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this case;

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format, culture-specific
>   format information, and style. **The format of the string representation
>   must match the specified format exactly.**

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("201010", "yyyyMM",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
  if (dt < DateTime.Now.Date)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(@"period cover must be higher than year and month now");
  }
}
```

But since you didn't write day part, your `dt` will be `01.10.2010` midnight as a default.

Comment: @JohnMarkQuizon You are quite welcome. Next time, please try to explain your problem more clear `;)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable with the "complete" `DateTime` not only the year+month:

```
public DateTime Period { get; set; } // initialize it accordingly
```

Now you can use it to show it in a different format, for example:

```
txtperiodcovered.Text = Period.ToString("MMyyyy");
```

or to compare it:

```
if (Period < DateTime.Now.Date){ }
```

On this way you don't need to always parse it from `string` to `datetime` and vice-versa and you don't run into localization issues.

However, if you need to convert a string to datetime anyway which only contains year and month use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime monthPeriod = DateTime.ParseExact("201010", "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // day amd time info is lost
```